# Allow page breaks in a dashed box

Tags: tikz-pgf

I use tikzpicture for my dashed box, but the box breaks to a newpage when the inside text is too long:

[image]

Here is my .tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}               
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{information text}=[draw=red, dashed, inner sep=1.5ex]
\node[text width=0.95\textwidth , information text]
{\begin{enumerate}           
    \item my item。
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item。
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
\end{enumerate}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I want my long dashed box can be continued in multi-page just like the longtable, how I can do that?

Comment: With `tcolorbox` this is quite simple. you only need to select option `breakable` ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution with the `mdframed` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\mdfsetup{tikzsetting={draw=red,line width=3pt,dashed,dash pattern= on 10pt off 3pt},linecolor=none}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\centering
\begin{mdframed}

{\begin{enumerate}
    \item my item。
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item。
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
\end{enumerate}}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

---

If you want a complete frame before and after the page break, use `everyline=true`.

```
\mdfsetup{tikzsetting={draw=red,line width=3pt,dashed,dash pattern= on 10pt off 3pt},linecolor=none,everyline=true}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. But it may miss the footline and headline with mdframed solution.

Comment: @StevenShen So you want two complete frames with four edges each?

Comment: @StevenShen does the second version satisfy your needs?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, the two complete frames with four edges each is what I want.I use `everyline=true` ,in my win10 there is something wrong with xelatex :`! Package keyval Error:everyline undefined.`, but it will be ok in my linux with texlive2015.

Answer (score 5):

And this is the solution with the `default` `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}               
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,breakable]
\begin{enumerate}           
    \item my item。
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item。
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
\end{enumerate}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Update: And with desired aspect (red, dashed border around all fragments)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}               
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}{empty, breakable, enhanced, colback=white, colframe=white,
overlay unbroken ={\draw[red, dashed, thick] (frame.north west) rectangle (frame.south east);},
overlay broken={\draw[red, dashed, thick] (frame.north west) rectangle (frame.south east);}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{mybox}
\begin{enumerate}           
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
\end{enumerate}
\end{mybox}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{mybox}
\begin{enumerate}           
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
    \item my item
\end{enumerate}
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]